# расположение за пределами сетки

Tags: html, css, css3

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Весь основной контент находится в сетке, а вот линии с кругом находятся за пределами сетки. Подскажите, как лучше это реализовать?

Comment: Думаю насчет псевдоэлементов, но хорошее ли это решение?

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос свои попытки реализации (свой код)

Comment: Какие линии с кругом, вы о чем?

Comment: @Леонид Елкин Что заставляет вас сомневаться в использовании :after/:before?

Comment: @Kirill Korushkin Отсутствие опыта. Делал через добавление лишних дивов, но понимаю, что это куча лишних строк кода в начале каждой секции, а их может быть огромное количество. Позже переделаю под плевдоэлементы.

Answer (score 0):

```css
    section{
      position:relativ;
   }
   .line {
        position:absolute;
        top: -40:
        left:0;
    }
```

Как вариант)

Comment: ну с позицей сам подберёшь) просто как пример поставил значения.

Comment: пример непонятный, ответы на SO принято писать самодостаточными, там где это возможно, а если использован сниппет что бы запускались и сразу был виден результат